# Unset an multidimensional array by key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-unset

```
$series = array();  

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
            $series[$row["data_id"]][] = $row; 
        }
```

The output from a `print_r` on `$series` yields for two example series:

> Array (
>
> [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [data_id] => 1 [time_id] => 1
>   [data] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [data_id] => 1 [time_id] => 2
>   [data] => 3 ) )
>
> [2] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 6 [data_id] => 2 [time_id] => 1
>   [data] => 7 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 7 [data_id] => 2 [time_id] => 2
>   [data] => 4 ) )

***My question:*** how do I unset the multidimensional array so it contains only *[data]* and none of the other keys? I still want `$series` to contain `[1]` and `[2]` but I do not want the respective sub-arrays to contain any other keys other than `[data]`.

In fact, since I am reducing the subarrays to contain a single key, I would really like to get rid of the subarrays altogether so that I have two arrays:

> $series[1] = array(1,3) and 
>   $series[2] = array(7,4)

Comment: why dont you `SELECT data` only? (in mysql query side of the script)

Comment: As I understand you can replace $series[$row["data_id"]][] = $row; with $series[$row["data_id"]][] = $row['data'];

Comment: Don't query your database for the columns that you don't need? Then there will be no reason to unset the other parts of the result set ie you only query the database for the `data` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$series = array();  

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
            $series[$row["data_id"]][] = $row['data']; 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can loop in your array and build a new one keeping only `data` details

```
$array = array ('1' => array ( '0' => array ( 'id' => 1, 'data_id' => 1, 'time_id' => 1, 'data' => 1 ), '1' => array ( 'id' => 2, 'data_id' => 1, 'time_id' => 2, 'data' => 3 ), ),
'2' => array ( '0' => array ( 'id' => 6, 'data_id' => 2, 'time_id' => 1, 'data' => 7 ), '1' => array ( 'id' => 7, 'data_id' => 2, 'time_id' => 2, 'data' => 4 ) ));

$i= 0;
$n= 0;
$series = array();
foreach($array as $dato)
{
    $series[$i] = array();
    foreach($dato as $data)
    {
        foreach($data as $key => $value)
        {
            if($key == 'data')
            {
                $series[$i][$n] = $value;
                $n++;
            }
        }
    }
    $n = 0;
    $i++;
}
var_dump($series);
```

This will output

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 1
      1 => int 3
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 7
      1 => int 4
```

#### [Live demo](http://ideone.com/PJWWS3)